# Hinge type 90degree max

Tags: hinge

I'm looking for a hinge

- that can open a maximum of 90 degrees
- will open fully by gravity alone
- approx 20mm wide
- approx 50mm long each arm
- approx 10mm thick when closed

Is this something that can be sourced?
Could it be 3D printed?

Comment: Is there a common name for hinges that cannot open past 90 degrees?

Comment: what makes you think that it would not be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full page of 90 degrees "stop" hinges for cabinets and doors. You have to browse through to find one that fits your need.

[image]

https://www.amazon.com/90-degree-stop-hinge/s?k=90+degree+stop+hinge